# Get minimum price of each product for given group(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have these simple tables:

#### `products`

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | code | details |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | P01  | ...     |
|  2 | P02  | ...     |
|  3 | P03  | ...     |
+----+------+---------+
```

#### `prices`

```
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | customerGroup | productCode | price  | date       | endDate    |
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
|  1 | DEFAULT       | P01         | 1.2500 | 2018-01-01 | NULL       |
|  2 | DEFAULT       | P02         | 1.4000 | 2018-01-01 | NULL       |
|  3 | DEFAULT       | P03         | 2.0000 | 2018-01-01 | NULL       |
|  4 | DEFAULT       | P01         | 1.3000 | 2018-07-01 | NULL       |
|  5 | BLUE          | P01         | 1.3100 | 2019-01-01 | NULL       |
|  6 | BLUE          | P02         | 0.9000 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-05-01 |
|  7 | BLUE          | P03         | 2.0000 | 2019-09-01 | NULL       |
|  8 | DEFAULT       | P01         | 1.3200 | 2019-10-01 | NULL       |
|  9 | GREEN         | P01         | 0.5000 | 2019-10-01 | NULL       |
| 10 | GREEN         | P02         | 0.6000 | 2019-10-01 | NULL       |
| 11 | GREEN         | P03         | 0.7000 | 2019-10-01 | NULL       |
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
```

#### Logic

- `prices` is a historical table.
- Each row represents a `price` record for a product and a customer group.
- `endDate = NULL` means `price` entry is valid between `date` and eternity (unless conditions below occur).
- If a `price` record for the same `customerGroup` and `productCode` has a newer *matching* `date`, it overrides the older ones — even if the `price` is higher.
- The minimum `price` value for the same `productCode` and matching date(s) will win; as long as the `customerGroup` it has matches with the given group(s).

#### Goal 1

To get the minimum possible price record:

- for a member of group `BLUE` and `DEFAULT`
- for product `P01`
- in date `2019-10-01`

```sql
SELECT
    pp.*
FROM prices AS pp
JOIN (
    SELECT customerGroup, MAX(date) AS maxDate
    FROM prices AS pp
    WHERE productCode = 'P01'
    GROUP BY customerGroup
) AS eachRow ON (pp.customerGroup = eachRow.customerGroup AND pp.date = eachRow.maxDate)
WHERE 
    pp.productCode = 'P01'
    AND FIND_IN_SET(pp.customerGroup, 'DEFAULT,BLUE') > 0
    AND ((pp.endDate IS NULL AND '2019-10-01' >= pp.date) OR (pp.endDate IS NOT NULL AND ('2019-10-01' BETWEEN pp.date AND pp.endDate)))
GROUP BY pp.customerGroup
ORDER BY pp.price ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

this returns the correct / expected single result:

```
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | customerGroup | productCode | price  | date       | endDate    |
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
|  5 | BLUE          | P01         | 1.3100 | 2019-01-01 | NULL       |
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
```

#### Goal 2 (Question)

How to get the minimum possible price **record** for each product in `products` at once?

The result should be:

```
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
| id | customerGroup | productCode | price  | date       | endDate    |
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
|  2 | DEFAULT       | P02         | 1.4000 | 2018-01-01 | NULL       |
|  5 | BLUE          | P01         | 1.3100 | 2019-01-01 | NULL       |
|  7 | BLUE          | P03         | 2.0000 | 2019-09-01 | NULL       |
+----+---------------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+
```

#### Notes:

- *I'm looking for a way to do this without using `GROUP_CONCAT` in the outer query.*
- *`MIN` + `GROUP BY` usage is not a solution since that won't properly return all necessary fields such as `customerGroup` and `date`...*

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c6f62/5).

Comment: You can replace `FIND_IN_SET(pp.customerGroup, 'DEFAULT,BLUE') > 0` with `pp.customerGroup IN ('DEFAULT', 'BLUE')`. It's simpler, standard, and might perform better.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you on? [Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) added in MySQL 8 would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

Goal 2 (Question)
How to get the minimum possible price record for each product in products at once?

The answer is:

```
Select p.productcode, min(p.price)
from prices p
left join products prd on p.productcode = prd.code
Group by p.productcode
```

output:
P01 0.5
P02 0.6
P03 0.7

But your request result is grouping by id, so it can not display the minimum price by product.  Also the actual data in the result you show is not actually the minimum price?  (which is confusing).

Comment: Thanks. But `min` + `group by` will not return all the required fields. The minimum prices in your result are wrong bec. those prices are for group `GREEN`. Pls read the question details in **logic** part.

Answer (score 1):

Query for second question

```
SELECT MAX(pp.customerGroup) as CustomerGroup, MAX(pp.ProductCode) as ProductCode , MIN(pp.price) as Price FROM Prices as pp
INNER JOIN Products as pro
on pp.PRoductCode = pro.Code

GROUP BY pp.customerGroup
ORDER BY pp.customerGroup;
```

Correct me if I am wrong I will update the answer accordingly..

Comment: If this is correct then will go for your first question.